# Not able to get the perfect sync for first batch in producer-consumer problem

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, producer-consumer, condition-variable

```
std::vector<infer_request_t*> infer_req_vec;
std::vector<infer_request_t*> infer_req_queue;

std::mutex produce_mutex;
std::condition_variable pcv;
std::condition_variable icv;

void produce_blobs(){

    bool enable_inf_stats = true;
    while(!stop_test && (batchCount < appargs.queryCount || appargs.isInfinite))
    {   
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> produce_lock(produce_mutex);
        pcv.wait_for(produce_lock, std::chrono::seconds(2),[]{return (((appargs.samplesPerQuery - infer_req_vec.size())>0));});
        if(stop_test || (batchCount >= appargs.queryCount && appargs.queryCount != -1)) break;
        // CODE FOR GENERATING IPBLOB AND OPBLOB FOR QUERY
        infer_request_t *infReq = NULL;
        infer_req_vec.push_back(infReq);
        int infer_req_vec_size = infer_req_vec.size();
        status = API(session, hEndPt, model, ipblob, opblob, enable_inf_stats, &infer_req_vec[infer_req_vec_size-1]);
        icv.notify_one();
        produce_lock.unlock();
        
    }
}

void infer_wait(){

    while(!stop_test && (batchCount < appargs.queryCount || appargs.isInfinite ))
    {
        infer_request_t* current_infer_req_wait;
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> infer_lock(produce_mutex);
            icv.wait(infer_lock,[]{return (((infer_req_vec.size()>0) && (infer_req_vec[0] != NULL)));});
            if(stop_test || (batchCount >= appargs.queryCount && appargs.queryCount != -1)) break;
            infer_req_queue.push_back(infer_req_vec[0]);
            infer_req_vec.erase(infer_req_vec.begin()+0);
            pcv.notify_one();
            infer_lock.unlock();
        }
        int queue_size = infer_req_queue.size();
        for(int i=0; i<queue_size; i++)
        {
            current_infer_req_wait = infer_req_queue[0];
            infer_req_queue.erase(infer_req_queue.begin()+0);
            //FURTHER PROCESSING ON `current_infer_req_wait`
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    std::thread t1(produce_blobs);
    std::thread t2(infer_wait);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

Above is the producer-consumer problem I have written.

`API` -  Takes batch of inputs and the batch number depends on the `appargs.samplesPerQuery`

The problem I am facing is, for the first batch until and unless it pushes all (`appargs.samplesPerQuery`) the input and output blobs, the `infer_wait` thread is not getting executed even though I am calling `icv.notify_one()` immediately.

**This happens only for the first batch** and from next time onwards, it happens in perfect synchronisation i.e. the moment `infer_wait()` consumes one request from `infer_req_queue` vector, the `produce_blobs()` pushes one more and this continues till end of the execution.

I would like to get this kind of perfect sync for the first batch also.

Please point if I am missing something or doing something wrong.

Thanks

Comment: What is `stop_test`? Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: By default `stop_test` is false and I have `close` function where I change the `stop_test` to true.